# Convert Android Share via File URI to FileProvider

Tags: android, android-studio, android-file, android-fileprovider

I am adapting an app written for Android API 22 to work with APIs 14 - 29. APIs 14 - 23 work without issue. However API 24 and up throw the error

```
exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

I know I can bypass this error via Strict Mode, but that is not the correct solution for App publication

```
val openFilePolicy = StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(openFilePolicy.build())
```

I've found that this means I have to use the FileProvider, but I'm having trouble understanding how to convert the current code to utilize the FileProvider. See below for current code:

```
val sendFile = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()+"/export_"+company+"_"+name+".csv")

//create intent to send to another app
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

//sharing csv as plain text
shareIntent.setType(".csv -> text/plain")

//need uri for file
val uri = Uri.fromFile(sendFile)

//send uri to next app
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)

//email to field
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf<String>("myEmail@hotmail.com", "otherEmail@hotmail.com"))

//email subject field
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share This File")

//email body field
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.emailBody) + " " + name + " " + getString(R.string.at) + " " + company)

//pop-up prompt
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share file to:"),0)
```